# How to include web.xml in build.xml while creating jar

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I cannot able to add like this.

How to include web.xml?

```
 <target name="jar" depends="compile">
 <jar destfile="webapp/ROOT/WEB-INF/jarDir/recommendation.jar" basedir="${dest}" webxml="${webapp}/web.xml"> </jar>
```

Comment: Why would a .jar file include a web.xml? .war files have web.xml, not .jar files.

Comment: OK.Then how to add this web.xml file?

Comment: Add it with what? Where? --- Also, why is the .jar file placed in the `WEB-INF/jarDir` folder? It should be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, in order to be in the classpath of a webapp. --- Before we can help, you need to show *what* you are trying to do. Do you understand the difference between a .jar file and a .war file? Do you understand the folder structure inside a .war file? If not, read the documentation.

Comment: Then read the Servlet documentation.

Comment: Why would a jar file be there in WEB-INF/jardir. It should be in WEB-INF/lib. Are you trying to deploy a webapp which contains jar file? In that case your jars should be in WEB-INF/lib and resources in META-INF/resources. Then your jar can access these resources.

Comment: @ deosha  thank you.Got it